# How to convert string to a datatype variable?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I have a .c file, which contains below line

`uint32 num_of_entries = 65;`

I am writing an automation script to open and create similar 'c' file and write the line "uint32 num_of_entries = " int(65)

Both files look similar, but the script created file throws undefined reference. I think it is because of how I am writing in string format. If that is the case do I need to change the string to any data type?

I am writing it as `file.write("uint32 num_of_entries = " + int(65))`

Comment: I think the first thing is you can't concatenate string with int in python

Comment: Probably look into format strings rather than adding an integer to a string

Comment: f-strings are cool: `file.write(f"uint32 num_of_entries = {65}")` or use the `str()` function to convert an object to string

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but you need to use f-strings or the `.format()` function to format the output:

```
# Using an f-string
file.write(f"uint32 num_of_entries = {65}")

# Using the `.format()` function:
file.write("uint32 num_of_entries = {0}".format(65))
```